# How to mute a mentioned member? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've tried to servermute a mentioned member, but it won't work.

```
const person = member.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
person.voice.setMute(true);
```

When I do "!mute" without a player mentioned it reacts (tested it with a reply message), but when I mention someone the bot just does nothing.
I also have a command to mute all members in a voicechannel and it works fine.

```
for (const [memberID, member] of message.member.voice.channel.members) {
                member.voice.setMute(true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the method you're using for getting the guild member is doesn't work. When using `<message>.mentions.members.first()`, you're already given a guild member. Along with this, you're checking for `.users`, which doesn't work

```js
const person = message.mentions.members.first() // Note the .members
person.voice.setMute(true);
```